# Error HTTP: 500 when uploading/sharing file in openmeetings

Tags: java, javascript, red5, openlaszlo, openmeetings

I have error HTTP: 500 when I try to upload a file or to share one in the white board.
I install openmeetings on windows 7 64 bits and I configured all things perfectly with compatible versions:
C:\ffmpeg\bin
C:\ImageMagick-6.6.4
C:\Program Files (x86)\SWFTools
C:\sox-14.4.0
C:\jodconverter-core-3.0-beta-4\lib

recording and video conference works perfectly.
How can I solve this problem ? Is there a problem with the SWFTools version 0.9.1 ?

Comment: You would probably do better contributing your question to http://serverfault.com or perhaps http://superuser.com . This question isn't really the specialty of stackoverflow. This question, as far as i can tell, is only distantly related to java.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a document you should have a look at the error message / convertion message.

OpenMeetings has mailing lists where those problems are discussed:
http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/mail-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

Were you running it in proxied mode on port 8080 (The default port of OpenLaszlo proxied mode)? If so, some routers/firewalls block this port. I encountered a similar problem myself when my boss and I were at a conference and that was the cause of the problem.

We have since changed our demo application to SOLO (no-proxied mode) which has solved our problem.